# Error message in Firefox when creating audio context

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, web-audio-api

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<script>
  var context = new window.AudioContext();
</script>
```

When I run this in Firefox 66.0.2 (64-bit) / Windows 10, I see in the console:

> InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

Audio works, i.e. I can connect e.g. an oscillator to the context:

```
var oscillator = context.createOscillator();
oscillator.connect(context.destination);
oscillator.start();
```

*So what's up with that error message?*

Comment: This error appears when just referencing `AudioContext`, without even instantiating it, I think it's a bug in Firefox.